# C++: shared_ptr as unordered_set's key

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, hash-function, unordered-set

Consider the following code

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::unordered_set<int> s;
    s.insert(5);
    s.insert(5);
    // s.size() == 1 

    boost::unordered_set<boost::shared_ptr<int> > s2;
    s2.insert(boost::make_shared<int>(5));
    s2.insert(boost::make_shared<int>(5));
    // s2.size() == 2
}
```

The question is: how come the size of s2 is 2 instead of 1? I'm pretty sure it must have something to do with the hash function. I tried looking at the boost docs and playing around with the hash function without luck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make_shared` allocates a new `int`, and wraps a `shared_ptr` around it. This means that your two `shared_ptr<int>`s point to *different memory*, and since you're creating a hash table keyed on pointer value, they are distinct keys.

For the same reason, this will result in a size of 2:

```
boost::unordered_set<int *> s3;
s3.insert(new int(5));
s3.insert(new int(5));
assert(s3.size() == 2);
```

For the most part you can consider `shared_ptr`s to act just like pointers, including for comparisons, except for the auto-destruction.

You could define your own hash function and comparison predicate, and pass them as template parameters to `unordered_map`, though:

```
struct your_equality_predicate
    : std::binary_function<boost::shared_ptr<int>, boost::shared_ptr<int>, bool>
{
    bool operator()(boost::shared_ptr<int> i1, boost::shared_ptr<int> i2) const {
        return *i1 == *i2;
    }
};

struct your_hash_function
    : std::unary_function<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::size_t>
{
    std::size_t operator()(boost::shared_ptr<int> x) const {
        return *x; // BAD hash function, replace with somethign better!
    }
};

boost::unordered_set<int, your_hash_function, your_equality_predicate> s4;
```

However, this is probably a bad idea for a few reasons:

1. You have the confusing situation where `x != y` but `s4[x]` and `s4[y]` are the same.
2. If someone ever changes the value pointed-to by a hash key **your hash will break**! That is:

   ```
   boost::shared_ptr<int> tmp(new int(42));
   s4[tmp] = 42;
   *tmp = 24; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
   ```

Typically with hash functions you want the key to be immutable; it will always compare the same, no matter what happens later. If you're using pointers, you usually want the pointer identity to be what is matched on, as in `extra_info_hash[&some_object] = ...`; this will normally always map to the same hash value whatever `some_object`'s members may be. With the keys mutable after insertion is it all too easy to actually do so, resulting in undefined behavior in the hash.

Comment: Right, ofcourse. So I should be nevertheless able to achieve the same semantics with the use of (smart) pointers as well? Meaning that by defining the hash function in some specific way the size would be 1 instead of 2. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in Boost <= 1.46.0, the default `hash_value` of a `boost::shared_ptr` is its boolean value, `true` or `false`.
For any `shared_ptr` that is not `NULL`, `hash_value` evaluates to 1 (one), as the `(bool)shared_ptr == true`.

In other words, you **downgrade a hash set to a linked list** if you are using Boost <= 1.46.0.

This is fixed in Boost 1.47.0, see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5216 .

If you are using `std::shared_ptr`, please define your own hash function, or use `boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp` from Boost >= 1.51.0

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, the two objects inserted into `s2` are distinct.